# How is it possible for an empty string to have a length greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, prototype, string-length

I came across this bug while trying to run a JS conditional to check for an empty string. In Chrome debugger, the empty string evaluates with a length of 1 and sometimes even 2. It's happening in a react app. I'm pretty lost as to how the proto still works correctly but the normal length method doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Is it whitespace? Or possibly a line break?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no character? Maybe you just can't see it ...

Comment: An empty string, by definition, has 0 characters. Thus the string shown is not empty: even if there are no *visible* characters. Use `value.charCodeAt(0)` to see what character is *really* there (`value[0]` won't be useful because it returns a string itself).

Comment: Just tried on Chrome console. `value = '' value.length // 0`

Comment: Ah yes, charCodeAt worked, thanks! It's apparently an enter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string may appear visibly empty when you ask for its value if the string contains characters that are not normal characters. These strings could be generated via the `String.fromCharCode` method or implicitly like `'\x0d'`. Characters such as Enter will appear to be an empty string. You can check for invisible characters using the `charCodeAt` method.

As Matus showed, this will replicate the behavior in question:

```
v = '\x0d'

console.log(v);        // ""
console.log(typeof v); // "string"
console.log(v[0]);     // "" 
console.log(v.length); // "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably on of these cases (invisible characters)

```js
v = '\x0d'

console.log(v);        // ""
console.log(typeof v); // "string"
console.log(v[0]);     // "" 
console.log(v.length); // "1"


v = '\x0d\x0d'

console.log(v);        // ""
console.log(typeof v); // "string"
console.log(v[0]);     // "" 
console.log(v.length); // "2";
```